# feature importance from autoxgboost models

Tags: r, mlr

I have models that are auto-tuned using autoxgboost which uses mlr as well and would you please advise how i can use the getFeatureImportance on the trained model?

```
system.time(tuned.labeled.autoxgboost <- autoxgboost(labeled_task))
preds.labeled.autoxgboost <- predict(tuned.labeled.autoxgboost$final.model, newdata = labeled_test)
class(tuned.labeled.autoxgboost)
[1] "AutoxgbResult"
class(tuned.labeled.autoxgboost$final.model)
[1] "CPOModel" "BaseWrapperModel" "WrappedModel"
getFeatureImportance(tuned.labeled.autoxgboost$final.model)
Error in UseMethod("getFeatureImportanceLearner") :
no applicable method for 'getFeatureImportanceLearner' applied to an object of class "c('regr.xgboost.custom', 'RLearnerRegr', 'RLearner', 'Learner')"
sapply(tuned.labeled.autoxgboost$final.model,class)
$learner
[1] "CPOLearner" "BaseWrapper" "Learner"

$learner.model
[1] "CPOWrappedModel" "ChainModel" "WrappedModel"

$task.desc
[1] "RegrTaskDesc" "SupervisedTaskDesc" "TaskDesc"

$subset
[1] "integer"

$features
[1] "character"

$factor.levels
[1] "list"

$time
[1] "numeric"

$dump
[1] "NULL"
```

Should i use the optimized parameters to set a xgboost learner in mlr and then run getFeatureImportance?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, getting feature importance from xgboost models isn't supported. You can of course implement it yourself, but we have no plans to do this in mlr.

Comment: Hi Lars, i thought it is supported: https://rdrr.io/cran/mlr/man/getFeatureImportance.html

Comment: Ah, in that case you should be able to apply it simply to the model trained with the best parameters, yes.